# `setState` not synced with UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am making a forum like website with a component to display different forums with a pagination button to show the next page using Next.js.

My current page implementation is that I am going to query data using `getServerSideProps` for initial page load. After that when user clicks on `Next page` button to show next page of the forum.

I wanted to query the same API that I have called in `getServerSideProps` to get the next page of the data.

I managed to get the button works. But the problem is that the number of `page` that is set by `setPage` doesn't seem to be synced up with the UI.

This is the code:

```typescript
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import type { GetServerSidePropsResult } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useState } from 'react'

import type { GetPostListRequestQueries } from '@/types/GetPostListRequestQueries'
import type { GetPostListResponseBody } from '@/types/GetPostListResponseBody'

export async function getServerSideProps (): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ announcements: GetPostListResponseBody }>> {
  const queries: GetPostListRequestQueries = {
    announcement: true,
    category_based_announcement: false,
    page: 1
  }

  try {
    const url = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5155/forum/posts')
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queries as Record<string, string>)
    url.search = searchParams.toString()

    const response = await fetch(url)
    const announcements: GetPostListResponseBody = await response.json()

    return {
      props: {
        announcements
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    const response: GetPostListResponseBody = {
      posts: []
    }

    return {
      props: {
        announcements: response
      }
    }
  }
}

function Forum ({ announcements }: { announcements: GetPostListResponseBody }): JSX.Element {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [pageAnnouncements, setPageAnnouncements] = useState(announcements)

  const fetchAnnouncements = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const queries: GetPostListRequestQueries = {
      announcement: true,
      category_based_announcement: false,
      page
    }

    try {
      const url = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5155/forum/posts')
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queries as Record<string, string>)
      url.search = searchParams.toString()

      const response = await fetch(url)
      const announcements: GetPostListResponseBody = await response.json()

      setPageAnnouncements(announcements)
    } catch (e) {
      const response: GetPostListResponseBody = {
        posts: []
      }

      setPageAnnouncements(response)
    }
  }

  async function goToPreviousPage (): Promise<void> {
    setPage(() => page - 1)
    await fetchAnnouncements()
  }

  async function goToNextPage (): Promise<void> {
    setPage(() => page + 1)
    await fetchAnnouncements()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Forum • ger</title>
        <meta name="description" content="reg spelled backwards" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <main className="container mx-auto">
        <h1 className="text-4xl text-current font-bold">Forum {page}</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-between">
          <h3 className="text-2xl text-current">Global announcements</h3>
          <div className="flex flex-row btn-group">
            <button className="btn" onClick={goToPreviousPage}>Previous page</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={goToNextPage}>Next page</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="overflow-x-auto">
          <table className="table w-full">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Topic</td>
                <td>Replies</td>
                <td>Views</td>
                <td>Activity</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                pageAnnouncements.posts.map(a => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={a.id}>
                      <td>
                        <Link className="font-bold link link-hover" href={{ pathname: '/forum/posts/[postId]', query: { postId: a.id } }}>{a.name}</Link>
                        <div className="flex flex-row">
                          <Link className="text-sm opacity-75 link link-hover" href={{ pathname: '/forum/users/[username]', query: { username: a.username } }}>
                            {a.username}
                          </Link>
                          <p className="text-sm opacity-75">
                             &nbsp;•&nbsp;{dayjs(a.created_timestamp).format('MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm')}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>10</td>
                      <td>{a.view_count}</td>
                      <td>1h</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <h3 className="text-2xl text-current font-bold">Trending</h3>
        <div className="overflow-x-auto">
          <table className="table w-full">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Cy Ganderton</td>
                <td>Quality Control Specialist</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Forum
```

You can see from the gif below that the number next to the word "Forum" and the number used when query is off by 1 all the time.

I am new to Nextjs and doesn't understand this kind of behavior. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

Calling `setState` does'nt immedialty update the related `state`. A re-render is needed. This how `setState` works by design. As the [doc](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) says:

> The `set` function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

In `goToPreviousPage` and `goToNextPage` you are calling `setPage` and immediately `fetchAnnouncements`, so it's using the value of `page` from the previous render.

## Solution

What you can do to make it work with little changes is to pass `page` to `fetchAnnouncements` as parameter, like so:

```typescript
const fetchAnnouncements = async (page: number): Promise<void> => {
 // ...
}
```

```typescript
async function goToPreviousPage (): Promise<void> {
  setPage(() => page - 1)
  await fetchAnnouncements(page - 1)
}

async function goToNextPage (): Promise<void> {
  setPage(() => page + 1)
  await fetchAnnouncements(page + 1)
}
```